# Deploying C# web application connecting to an Oracle database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle

As we tried to deploy a new project that connects to an Oracle database, we encountered some problems..

On my development workstation, I have my Oracle dll's installed in c:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN but on the development web server, it's in stalled in c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN (noticed NOT in the app folder).

When an application is deployed, those dll's that are referenced need to be in the same location on both machines. So needless to say, we get an error from the development server.

In order to fix this, we tried a few things -

1. Move the Oracle install to c:\app... on my machine and rebuild from my development machine. This didn't work because there are relative dll's that rely on that path.
2. Because 1 didn't work, we tried to reset the environment path variables to c:\oracle on my machine. That didn't work.
3. tried to copy the needed dll's into my bin directory because my understanding is Visual Studio will build from the GAC, then from the bin directory. That didn't work.

Knowing that re-installing Oracle on the development server to c:\app\Oracle isn't an option, has anyone else come across this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that your Oracle install is setup correctly.  I have a few utilities that can assist with this.

Step 1 -

The utilities below will confirm first that .net works with Oracle on your server
http://tsells.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/oracle-connection-tester-for-net-applications/

Step 2 -

If the utility above worked - then go to step 3.  Otherwise - .net can't see oracle on this machine.  Check your path statement first - make sure the oracle bin directory is pointing to is the correct one.  If not - change it and try again.

If this doesn't work - I recommend uninstalling oracle completely and reinstalling.  Use the following steps.

1. Stop any services (start - run - services.msc) below that are running

   - oracle mts recovery
   - Distributed Transaction Coordinator
2. Delete all oracle directories from the file system (C:\app, C:\Program Files | C:\Program Files (x86(
3. Remove Oracle entries from the system path
4. Remove any Oracle entries from the environment variables (if they exist) such as ORACLE_HOME
5. Open the registry editor (start -- run -- regedit) and remove any oracle entries from the following key

HKLM\Software\
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node   (64 bit machines only)

1. Empty Recycle bin (makes me feel better) :)
2. Reboot the machine
3. Download one of the two items

Oracle Client Installation (full)

ODAC (Oracle Data Providers)

1. Install them (make sure if you choose the client version - you use a minimum of the runtime install) - do NOT use the instant client - it never seems to work properly.
2. Copy the TNSNames.ora file over
3. Test with the utility again. It should be successful.

Step 3 -

If the utility above worked - then you need to make sure the bit level of your application matches the bit level of the Oracle client installation.  For the app - this will be the bit level of the application pool.

Notes - the oracle.dataaccess.dll file in the bin folder is used to help create the images (ngen, aspnet compilation).  Once you attempt to call the oracle data provider for .net - it is routed to your client installation to perform the actually data access.